# Filter Json in List of Json stored in a CLOB Field (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have been trying to modify a CLOB field in a Oracle DB (for performance reason) which stores an array of json.

Consider this trivial example

```
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | COL |                                                                Json                                                                |
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10 |  12 | [{"id":4, "name":"Jhon", age:40, opinion:null},{"id":3, name:"Jane", age:7},{"id":7, "name":"Peter", age:12, opinion:"somevalue"}] |
| 20 |  27 | [{"id":10, "name":"Julian", age:40, opinion:"somevalue"}]                                                                          |
| 30 |  40 | [{"id":30, "name":"Paul", age:20, opinion:"opinion"},{"id":3, name:"Jane", age:7}]                                                 |
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My objective is to obtain a table in which the `Json` column (it is a CLOB, as it may be very large) has to be filtered based on a condition. In this example, suppose the condition is to remove all the jsons with `opinion = "somevalue"`. The result would be:

```
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | COL |                                        Json                                        |
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10 |  12 | [{"id":4, "name":"Jhon", age:40, opinion:null},{"id":3, name:"Jane", age:7}]       |
| 20 |  27 | []                                                                                 |
| 30 |  40 | [{"id":30, "name":"Paul", age:20, opinion:"opinion"},{"id":3, name:"Jane", age:7}] |
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**MY ATTEMPT:**

I have tried to address this problem with JSON_ARRAYAGG function, but it does not work. I mean, it works assumed that I do not limit the query to a specific id. This is the query:

```sql
UPDATE table t SET t.JSON = (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'id' VALUE jt.id,
        'opinion' VALUE jt.opinion,
        'age' VALUE jt.age,
        'name' VALUE jt.name
      ) RETURNING CLOB )
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    t.JSON, '$[*]'
    COLUMNS (
      age NUMBER PATH '$.age',
      opinion VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.opinion',
      id number PATH '$.id',
      name VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.name'
    )
) jt WHERE jt.opinion <> 'somevalue');
```

if I modify it like that:

```sql
UPDATE table t SET t.JSON = (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'id' VALUE jt.id,
        'opinion' VALUE jt.opinion,
        'age' VALUE jt.age,
        'name' VALUE jt.name
      ) RETURNING CLOB )
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    t.JSON, '$[*]'
    COLUMNS (
      age NUMBER PATH '$.age',
      opinion VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.opinion',
      id number PATH '$.id',
      name VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.name'
    )
) jt WHERE jt.opinion <> 'somevalue') WHERE t.id = 10;
```

I receive a wrong expected value on the only modified row (like all the json of all the rows in the single modified row). I would like to understand what's going on and if the approach is right.

PS: please consider that `JSON` is not the real name of the col, and so it does not conflict with anything.

Comment: There is no where clause in the inner select so you get all rows. Restrict that inner select so it only fetches the json for t.id = 10;.

Comment: You are right! But then why the first one is working?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 19.10 or higher, it's easier to use `json_transform`.

The search expression `'$[*]?(@.opinion == "somevalue")'` identifies array elements where opinion is "somevalue". Using this with the `remove` clause deletes those entries from the document:

```
with rws ( id, j ) as (
  select 10, '[{"id":4, "name":"Jhon", age:40, opinion:null},{"id":3, name:"Jane", age:7},{"id":7, "name":"Peter", age:12, opinion:"somevalue"}]' from dual union all
  select 20, '[{"id":10, "name":"Julian", age:40, opinion:"somevalue"}]'  from dual union all
  select 30, '[{"id":30, "name":"Paul", age:20, opinion:"opinion"},{"id":3, name:"Jane", age:7}]'  from dual 
)
  select json_transform (
    j,
    remove '$[*]?(@.opinion == "somevalue")'
  )
  from   rws;
  
JSON_TRANSFORM(J,REMOVE'$[*]?(@.OPINION=="SOMEVALUE")')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"id":4,"name":"Jhon","age":40,"opinion":null},{"id":3,"name":"Jane","age":7}]
[]
[{"id":30,"name":"Paul","age":20,"opinion":"opinion"},{"id":3,"name":"Jane","age":7}]
```